# dimension of tensor products over a submodule

Tags: ring-theory, tensor-products

Let $k$ be a field, $A$ be a finite dimensional $k$-algebra (say of dimension $n_A$) and let $B\subset A$ be a sub-algebra.  What can be said about the $k$-dimension of $A \otimes_B A$ ?

The easiest case is when $A$ is $B$-free of rank $r_A$.  Then $A \otimes_B A$ has $B$-rank $r_A^2$, and $k$-dimension $n_B^{r_A^2}$ (I think).

What about when $A$ is $B$-projective?  Or, say, that $A = \text{span}_B\{c_1,\ldots,c_{r_A}\}$, but each $a\in A$ can be written as exactly $b_1 c_1 + \ldots + b_{r_A} c_{r_A}$ for exactly $s$ tuples $(b_1,\ldots,b_{r_A})$ ? (I'm thinking here that $s$ is like a measure of $A$'s failure to be $B$-free.)  Is there a nice formula that can be worked out?

or a reference for these sorts of thing?

Comment: cf. [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2363186/k-dimension-of-tensor-product-of-two-modules-over-a-k-algebra) question.